# PowerShell: convert array to html table

Tags: html, powershell, converters

How would I convert simple array of hashes in PowerShell to HTML table?

```
$array = @{

"Name" = "My Name"
"Surname" = "My Surname"
"Address" = "My Address"
"DateOfBirth" = "My Date Of Birth"
"Hobby" = "My Hobby"
 "Age" = "My Age" 
 }
```

[image]

And then just keep adding rows? Has anyone achieved this before? Below I will provide examples of that I've tried so far according to several online forums:

```
[System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]$array | ConvertTo-Html
-Fragment
```

> Cannot convert the "System.Collections.Hashtable" value of type
>   "System.Collections.Hashtable" to type
>   "System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject". At line:0 char:0
>   + [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject]$array | ConvertTo-Html  ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException

```
New-Object psobject -Property $array | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
```

> System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
>   System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
>   System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry

```
$array | Select 'Name','Surname','Address','DateOfBirth','Hobby', 'Age' | ConvertTo-HTML -Fragment
```

> System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
>   System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
>   System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry

```
 $array | Select 'Name','Surname','Address','DateOfBirth','Hobby', 'Age' | ConvertTo-HTML -as Table -Fragment
```

> System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
>   System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
>   System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry

```
$array | Select 'Name','Surname','Address','DateOfBirth','Hobby', 'Age' | ConvertTo-HTML -as Table -Fragment | Out-String
```

> System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
>   System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
>   System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry

```
$table = $array.GetEnumerator() | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -As Table
```

[image]

```
$table = $array.GetEnumerator() | select "Name", "Surname", "Address", "DateOfBirth", "Hobby", "Age" | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -As Table
```

[image]

As you can see, so many different approaches, and none of them led to success :-(

Comment: Your initial `How would I convert simple array` and the error msg `Cannot convert the "System.Collections.Hashtable"` should tell you, where you got it wrong: `@{}` creates a hashtable not a simple arry.

Comment: @LotPings let me rephrase the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
$table = [PSCustomobject]$array| ConvertTo-Html -Fragment -As Table
$table
```

---

```
<table>
<colgroup><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th><th>Surname</th><th>DateOfBirth</th><th>Hobby</th><th>Address</th></tr>
<tr><td>My Name</td><td>My Age</td><td>My Surname</td><td>My Date Of Birth</td><td>My Hobby</td><td>My Address</td></tr>
</table>
```

From what source do you want to add rows?

Answer (score 1):

'11','22','33' | ForEach{[PSCustomObject]@{'My Column Name'=$_}} | ConvertTo-HTML -Fragment -Property 'My Column Name'

Your output would then be:

```
<table>
<colgroup><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>My Column Name</th></tr>
<tr><td>11</td></tr>
<tr><td>22</td></tr>
<tr><td>33</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is not related to my question. I rather have more complex hash table. But thanks for taking time and answering the question